# my hyperlink generated in django doesn't work

Tags: python, html, django, hyperlink

So I have the following environment; `django 1.8`. `apache` on `ubuntu 14` with `mod_wsgi` and `mod x-sendfile` enabled.

I have a very simple view to server the files as follows:

```
def foo(request, filename):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = "/home/amir/DjV/Files/{0}".format(filename)
    return response
```

and here's my urlconf regarding the view:

```
url(r'^foo/(.+)/$', foo)
```

I've written a snippet that generate absolute path to files to be presented in a download list. The generated paths work fine if I enter them in the browser; but if I use them as hyperlinks, when clicked it goes to blank page. For examlple here is one the urls that is generated by the snippet I mentioned:

```
http://192.168.43.6:8000/foo/uuid.txt
```

it works fine and I get to download the uuid.txt, but when I put it into django template as follows, it doesn't work:

```
<a href="192.168.43.6:8000/foo/uuid.txt">192.168.43.6:8000/foo/uuid.txt </a>
```

**My question being:** why my link works fine when entered manually but not when used as a hyperlink? Could it be because of being a local address? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a protocol inside your template when doing such things:

```
<a href="http://192.168.43.6:8000/foo/uuid.txt">192.168.43.6:8000/foo/uuid.txt </a>
```

However, you should not hard code urls in this way in special not if they are handled inside your Django application. Check {% url %} templating whether it could be a benefit for you

Comment: Thanks a lot; I definitely will look into the url tag.